# How to get last error message from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using `debug_backtrace()` and some basic styling to log my website errors.

```
if (@mysql_error($this->conn))
   $error = 'mysql_error() response: ' . @mysql_error($this->conn);
else
   $error = 'non mysql error\r\n';
```

Sometimes it doesn't work. My log files are full of *"non mysql error"* but the errors always appear in functions which has database connections. Like, `getAllNews()` function fails, but it logs it as non mysql error.

How can I log errors of my website and mysql correctly?

Comment: you report an error (just not with MySQL) when a connection is sucessful? On failure, you should `die` ASAP

Comment: Don't suppress errors with `@`. It makes debugging a pain in the butt. There are better ways to check for errors.

Comment: Just found this on the mysql_error() page, might be worth looking into `Be aware that if you are using multiple MySQL connections you MUST support the link identifier to the mysql_error() function. Otherwise your error message will be blank.

Just spent a good 30 minutes trying to figure out why i didn't see my SQL errors.`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php#96003

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: ** obligatory mysql_xx functions are deprecated comment ** Use MySQLi or PDO instead - which means you'll need to look into how to trace errors with them rather than mysql_error() | mysql_errno() [damn ninja'd :P ]

Comment: Post more of the code that surrounds the snippet you've given us. You may be incorrectly checking for an error condition and these 'non mysql errors' are false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to log error immediately after "error-able" mysql functions. And AFAIK, all error-able functions return `FALSE` on error, so you can check as below;

```
<?php
public function errorLog($error) {
    // concat error with mysql error
    $error .= $this->conn
        ? mysql_error($this->conn)
        : mysql_error();
    // log error
    error_log($error);
    // keep last error
    $this->_lastError = $error;
}

...

// remember suppressing error throws (with "@" sign)
$this->conn =@ mysql_connect(...);
if (false === $this->conn) {
    $this->errorLog("Connection failed: ");
}
//or
$query =@ mysql_query(...);
if (false === $query) {
    $this->errorLog("Query failed: ");
}
?>
```